# How to pass a wildcard parameter to a bashrc function

Tags: linux, bash, function, wildcard

I have a function set up in my `.bashrc` file to allow me to easily run a command that I use often in my day to day worfklow. The function in question:

```
chkerrors () { egrep -i 'page allocation failure|oom-killer|soft lockup|blocked for more' "$1"; }
```

I typically will run this on a single file such as:

```
$ chkerrors /var/log/messages
```

However there are instances where the messages files have been rotated out, so there will be multiple messages files.

Simply running the same command and throwing a wildcard on the end doesn't seem to work properly:

```
$ chkerrors /var/log/messages*
```

My question is, how can I adjust my function in order to allow me to run a command similar to the above with a wild card?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `chkerrors /var/log/messages*`, the glob will be expanded by `bash` before it calls the function, e.g. the actual function call is `chkerrors /var/log/messages1 /var/log/messages2 /var/log/messages3`.

That means the function receives multiple parameters, but you only handle the first one, `$1`. You will instead want to handle all its parameters using `"$@"` :

```
chkerrors () { egrep -i 'page allocation failure|oom-killer|soft lockup|blocked for more' "$@"; }
```

`"$@"` is special in that it doesn't expand to a single word as the quotes generally imply, but rather to a list of quoted words, so each file matched by the glob will be treated as an additional parameter of your `egrep` command, and files containing character of the IFS will correctly be treated as a single parameter rather than splitted in two.